# How to fill empty areas with copper fill on PCB?

Tags: pcb, rf

I am trying to create a copper layer. How do I fix the empty zones that are not filled with copper?

[image]

Comment: I would consider rearranging your components to be better grouped beside the things they connect to. That will largely take care of the large gaps.

Answer (score 2):

Those are islands and the CAD program has refused to fill them because they are almost always undesirable. You could probably lose the peninsulas in the lower left too, or at least add vias to your bottom plane if you are adding one. If that is KiCAD, then there should be an option in the zones dialog to fill islands but you should only add them if you *really* need them.

Comment: How do I know if I need them

Comment: will the PCB still work if I don't fill in those spaces?

Comment: Yes, the PCB will still work. There's no real electrical benefit to having large unconnected chunks of copper floating around on your board. They can even have detrimental effects if signals couple into or out of them. If the empty areas are large, your fab might want to fill them with a pattern to help balance etching rates across the board but you should really start thinking about current supply and return paths instead of pouring copper everywhere it'll fit; it will save you headaches down the road.

Comment: Ground and Power Planes are a good thing. Isolated floating planes are trouble get rid of them unless you want to start trouble and create a problem to fix.